# How to separate write access to Maven repositories in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

In order to prevent that one build influences another it is possible to configure a Jenkins project to use a own private Maven repository. However, because we have actually a huge list of dependencies, this leads to a lot of wasted disk space and to slow builds. We use a Maven repository proxy, but still the time to download artifacts over the local network is significant.

I could set up another repository proxy directly on the Jenkins machine. Is there an easier solution?

I still want that any "maven install" goes to a project-specific repo, while reading of artifacts that have not been deployed to that project-specific repo should come from a central place on the local file-system. Those artifacts should **not** be copied for performance and disk space reasons.

To explain the background I append the help text of the "Use private Maven repository" option:

> "Normally, Jenkins uses the local Maven repository as determined by
>   Maven — the exact process seems to be undocumented, but it's
>   ~/.m2/repository and can be overridden by  in
>   ~/.m2/settings.xml (see the reference for more details.)
>
> This normally means that all the jobs that are executed on the same
>   node shares a single Maven repository. The upside of this is that you
>   can save the disk space, but the downside of this is that sometimes
>   those builds could interfere with each other. For example, you might
>   end up having builds incorrectly succeed, just because your have all
>   the dependencies in your local repository, despite that fact that none
>   of the repositories in POM might have them.
>
> There are also some reported problems regarding having concurrent
>   Maven processes trying to use the same local repository.
>
> When this option is checked, Jenkins will tell Maven to use
>   $WORKSPACE/.repository as the local Maven repository. This means each
>   job will get its own isolated Maven repository just for itself. It
>   fixes the above problems, at the expense of additional disk space
>   consumption.
>
> When using this option, consider setting up a Maven artifact manager
>   so that you don't have to hit remote Maven repositories too often.
>
> If you'd prefer to activate this mode in all the Maven jobs executed
>   on Jenkins, refer to the technique described [here](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Hudson-on-2-4-8-16-core-boxes-td371215.html#a371217)."

Answer (score 2):

You could have:

- one settings.xml that points to a common local repository, used for every mvn clean package command
- and one settings.xml per projet that uses a specific local repository for every mvn install command

In order you would:

```
mvn clean package -s settings-common.xml # using common-repo
mvn install -s settings-jobX.xml # using jobX-repo
```

The only issue is that the artifact installed by your job wouldn't be available to other jobs if they need it. You'd have to either deploy, or copy manually the artifact to the common-repo.

Please note that I do not understand fully what you mean by "one build influences another". You should clarify that in order to have a better answer (because what you want to do might not be what's best to do).

Comment: Good idea, could work! The goal of my projects is test, not deployment (while maven deploy is still needed because it's about multi-module projects. "one build influences another": If project A deploys to a repository R, the state of R is changed. This can influence a build of project B when R is used for B. This is especially true if you have feature branches and thus the same Maven coordinates for different concurrent builds. Build B could use an artifact that was build by A when it should use the one built by itself.

Comment: Suppose you have a project with a master branch (or trunk in SVN), and a feature branch. Then, in your pom.xml I suggest you set two different versions. This way, when you deploy to any repository, the artifacts ARE different (ID is groupId + artifactId + version).

Comment: See Maven documentation for _version_:

version: This is the last piece of the naming puzzle. groupId:artifactId denote a single project but they cannot delineate which incarnation of that project we are talking about. Do we want the junit:junit of today (version 4), or of four years ago (version 2)? In short: code changes, those changes should be versioned, and this element keeps those versions in line. It is also used within an artifact's repository to separate versions from each other. my-project version 1.0 files live in the directory structure $M2_REPO/org/codehaus/mojo/my-project/1.0.`

Comment: Using a different version for each feature branch is not an option.

Comment: I understand that constraints exist, especially when the project is not your own in a company for example. But trust me, speaking from experience with Maven, you really want to do things like they were designed to be done or Maven is going to bite you really hard at the end... And when I say "change you version", it can be as simple as "1.0-SNAPSHOT" for your master, and "1.0-FEATURE" for the branch until you merge.

Comment: As the purpose is testing and artifacts are not published, I doubt that it would be desirable to do the versioning here. You do not version your local workspace builds, do you? This would be an interesting discussion, but beyond the scope of my problem and question.

Comment: @Gustave Why do you need a deploy for testing: `while maven deploy is still needed because it's about multi-module projects.` Can you explain this a little bit more?

Comment: I am not completely sure because we have a quite complex build. But it involves several maven modules in a reactor and some of the maven plugins require a deployment of some modules to the local repo in an earlier step of the build.